# How do I create a custom template for view?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have created a content type called "Hotels". I want to display to the view in different manner other than view options provided by Views module. For that I have to create custom template but don't know how to do it. What should be the naming conventions and where to store the template file. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that you are just saying what you want to do without asking any explicit question. It's not clear what exactly you don't understand in what you need to do, what exactly you already did, or what exactly you know. We cannot copy-paste all the documentation available on the topic, hoping we tell you something you missed, or did wrong.

Comment: I am sorry, but if you don't know anything about creating a custom template for a view, you first need to read the available documentation.

Comment: To get started, and narrow down your question later on, have a look at the answers to some of [these questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=[theming][views][8]+is%3Aq+answers%3A1+template)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create custom template for that view, create file and give name to that template as **views-view-fields--viewname--page/block.html.twig** and then create the HTML structure and then simply print the field accordingly and then save the file and don't forget to flush the cache.

To print the field...suppose you want to print the title and image field then do as below **{{ fields.title.content}}** **{{fields.machine_name_of_image_field.content}}**
thats it.

**Note:** To get the machine name of the field, goto the content type and then manage fields, there you will find machine name of those fields. And remember if you have not add field in view in admin panel and adding it in your template file then it will not reflect.

Comment: Notice that the first version of the question speaks of _unformatted view_. Does an _unformatted view_ use fields?

Comment: Absolutely!! Without fields there will be nothing to display in the view.

Comment: It doesn't seem so. http://i.stack.imgur.com/4RZwM.png

Comment: In the view you mentioned you are using show  as "content", but there is another option too i.e "fields". Try that also.Once you select that then you must select fields which you want to display in fields.By default "Title" field is selected...I am new to stack overflow so I don;t know how to upload image otherwise I've screenshot of the unformatted view using fields which i created for one of my website.

Comment: You said that without fields there would not be anything to show in the view. I proved it is not true, since the default front page view doesn't use any field.

Comment: Oh..My Bad...I was only talking regarding show: fileds... :)

Comment: if /admin/structure/views/view/event_related/edit/page_1 then views-view-fields--event_related--page-1.html.twig

Answer (score 8):

Below give are the views template suggestion allowed in Drupal 8.

- views-view--foobar--page.html.twig
- views-view--page.html.twig
- views-view--foobar.html.twig
- views-view.html.twig
- views-view-unformatted--foobar--page.html.twig
- views-view-unformatted--page.html.twig
- views-view-unformatted--foobar.html.twig
- views-view-unformatted.html.twig
- views-view-fields--foobar--page.html.twig
- views-view-fields--page.html.twig
- views-view-fields--foobar.html.twig
- views-view-fields.html.twig

Refer [Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Create a services.yml file (an example file is under sites/default)

In that file, set  debug: true (set to false in example file)

Save the file and clear you cache.

If you go to your view and inspect the code it will show you all of the theme suggestions you can use (similar to what theme info did in Views 3)