# How can I set the template to use for a view page display?

Tags: views, theming

I created a view for my content, where fields are displayed as a page.
Scanning the source code, I noticed it uses the *html--default--2.html.twig* template.

I created a new custom template. how can I set that template for all the view pages, instead of the default template? I need to edit the whole page, including header and footer.

Notice that I've read [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x) and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208796/how-do-i-create-a-custom-template-for-view) about custom templates for view.
I've tried to rename my custom template *views-view--page.html.twig*, and put it in my template folder, and also in /core/modules/views/templates, flushed cache, but nothing happens. My view page is still using the default template.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add new page template only for views:

1. Implement [hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  //- Get the current route name.
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  //- Check if the current route is a view.
  if (strpos($route_name, 'view') === 0) {
    //- Add suggestion to page when its a view page.
    $suggestions[] = 'page_views_view';
  }
}
```

Now in your views page you will have suggestions something like:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x page-views-view.html.twig
   * page--en.html.twig
   * page--list-page.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
```

1. Now implement [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x) like the following:

```
/**
 2. Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'page_views_view' => [
      'base hook' => 'page',
    ],
  ];
}
```

3. Then Create `page-views-view.html.twig` template inside `templates` folder in your module root folder.
4. Flush all cache.

Comment: thanks. I'm quite new to code...is correct to past your code in .theme file, in my theme folder?

Comment: it's better to create custom module check examples module for developers [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) to see how to create custom module, and place the above code in your `.module` file enable the module, it will work.

Comment: thnk you. I added your code to this file, in example module you suggested me: /modules/examples/hooks_example/hooks_example.module
but nothing happens, page suggestion doesn't work...
  "page-views-view.html.twig" doesn't appear in theme suggestion.

Is correcto to replace 
 if (strpos($route_name, 'view') === 0) {
with
 if (strpos($route_name, 'view') == 0) {
? anyway it doesn't work...should I try with completely new custom module?

Comment: change `mymodule` by your module name, e.g `mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)` will be `hooks_example_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)` and then enable `hooks_example` module, clear cache then should work.